# Data shows incorrectly when imported from csv into SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I am using SSIS to import a file into SQL Server 2008. This file is supplied in `.csv` format to me via someone else. I have no control over the export of the file.

When I import the file the one field shows e.g. `01.10111144000000000000000e+009` instead of `1101111440`.

I then proceeded to open it up in Notepad and Excel and that is how it shows up as well. When I right-click on that column in Excel and select 'Format Cells' and set it to General it reflects correctly.  Problem is I can't do this manually.

What can I do prior to doing a bulk insert from the file to make sure that the column will import correctly?

Comment: Is this a question about how to import the data into SQL Server, or some other program (e.g. Notepad, Excel) ?

Comment: HI there.  It's about loading it from the file into SQL.  Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: The problem here is that you're looking at how the data appears when you _export_ it into something like Notepad, when your real concern should be whether you imported all relevant infomation into SQL.  Assuming those decimal figures are meaningful, it looks like your probably did get the data in SQL successfully.  What do you plan to do in SQL with the data?

Comment: 01.10111144000000000000000e+009 should actually be a VARCHAR when imported to SQL and display as 1101111440 as this what we call an item code.  From there the front-end developer will be up the data, using this code as part of the primary key to display data in a report.  Does this make sense?

Comment: When I load it into the table and then do a simple select and CONVERT(FLOAT, CodeField) it display it correctly.  But when I CONVERT that selection to VARCHAR I get an overflow error.

Comment: This sounds like your `VARCHAR` column is not wide enough.  Make it wider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for importing data from CSV to SQL Server database.

```
    DECLARE @filePath VARCHAR (200)
        ,@basePath VARCHAR(200) = 'C:\Dumps\'
        ,@Bulk NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Get full file path
SET @filePath = @basePath + 'reportsdump.csv';

-- Populate table [#ReportsDumpData] with data from csv.
SET @Bulk = 'BULK INSERT #ReportsDumpData  FROM '''+@filePath+''' WITH (';
SET @bulk += 'FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ''";"'' , rowterminator=''\n'')';
EXEC(@Bulk);
```

Answer (score 0):

The joys of having to work with other people's extracts.  I loaded it into a temp (staging) table.  From there I first convert it to a float which I convert into a decimal(10, 0) and convert that to a varchar(10).  This works.